# Как разделить повторяющиеся классы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

В общем, есть вот такой код:

```
$('.post-more-trigger').click( function() {
    $('.post-more').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.post-more-trigger').toggleClass('active');
});
```

На стр. много повторяющихся блоков с этими классами, в каждой статье свой.
При нажатии срабатывают все, мне нужно разделить их. Чтобы при нажатии на .post-more-trigger срабатывал определенный post-more.

Comment: Как связаны post-more и post-more-trigger!? html код покажите

Comment: Можно как-нибудь так http://jsfiddle.net/nhzvv4hb/
Или так http://jsfiddle.net/nhzvv4hb/1/ в случае, если post-more в одном контейнере с post-more-trigger.. По разному можно.

Comment: @moron, у вас ошибка, active по прежнему добавляется ко всем элементам, вот так правильно: http://jsfiddle.net/nhzvv4hb/2/

Comment: @MasterAlex, спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: @MasterAlex, ну, пропустил :) Просто стили не ставил и, соответственно, не заметил.